# Best Practices for Assigning Unique Identifiers (keys, ids, etc.) To Distinct Code Entities

Tags: javascript, performance, global-variables, react-router, url-routing

I'm not quite sure how best to express the idea. I'm working on a note-taking application of sorts, wherein I would ultimately like to have functionality allowing the user to generate as many notes as s/he wishes for whatever purpose. These notes are shown in smaller "thumbnail"-like views on login. For example, the note thumbnails view might look something like this:
[image]

However, when the user clicks on a particular note, the intent is that s/he will be redirected to a URL route unique to that note... a route specific to that note wherein the user can edit the note in its entirety. For example:

[image]

My query is rather general, not by any means unique to this scenario. (Though I hope it helps to describe my question). Specifically, what are the conventions for creating unique identifiers by which to distinguish each individual note? At the simplest, one might think of just creating an index variable and incrementing every time a new note is added, but this is certainly too trivial. How are such things handled in more professional, production applications?

The reason this is of importance to my application is that I'm using React-Router for... routing. In order to make this routing work as described, I need to be able to pass a parameter in the route configuration. For example:

```
<Route path="/notes/:noteId">
```

would take interpolate the `noteId` parameter to redirect to the appropriate URL path. Again, I'm sure there are plenty of trivial ways to handle the issue of assigning unique identifiers to each individual note from the collective lot. But I am more interested in what the better ways are of handling things like this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this react/redux tutorial https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage Dan Abramov uses this package: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-uuid
or else you can generate unique ids using Date.now()

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help!